# possible ways of making sum of odd even indexes after removing an element

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need to write a JavaScript function that takes in an array of numbers as the first and the only argument.

The function then removes one element from the array, upon removal, the sum of elements at odd indices is equal to the sum of elements at even indices. The function should count all the possible unique ways in which we can remove one element at a time to achieve balance between odd sum and even sum.

Example
var arr = [2, 6, 4, 2];

Then the output should be 2 because, there are two elements 6 and 2 at indices 1 and 3 respectively that makes the combinations table.

When we remove 6 from the array

[2, 4, 2] the sum at odd indexes = sum at even indexes = 4

if we remove 2

[2, 6, 4] the sum at odd indices = sum at even indices = 6

I found this code below, that seems to work, but the problem is I cant understand how? Can someone explain me the logical process behind the code below so I won't just copy paste it but actually understand it?

```
const arr = [2, 6, 4, 2];
const check = (arr = []) => {
  var oddTotal = 0;
  var evenTotal = 0;
  var result = 0;
  const arraySum = []
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        evenTotal += arr[i];
        arraySum[i] = evenTotal
        
      } 
      else {
        oddTotal += arr[i];
        arraySum[i] = oddTotal
      } 
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
         if (arraySum[i]*2 - arr[i] + oddTotal === (arraySum[i - 1] || 0)*2 + evenTotal) {
           result = result +1
          };
        } else if (arraySum[i]*2 - arr[i] + evenTotal === (arraySum[i - 1] || 0)*2 + oddTotal) {
          result = result +1
      }
   }
   return result;
};
```

Comment: I thank you guys for all your comments. But can someone explain me how the code I posted work please, I'd really want to know

Answer (score 0):

here is simple algo

```
func(){
 int temp[arr.size()][2]
 for i in range(arr.size()-1,0):
    temp[i][0]=sum of odd terms on right(after) of i
    temp[i][1]=sum of even terms on right(after) of i
 
 //Now start from the left side of array, the trick is if you remove 
 //one element from the array, the sum of odd terms and even terms of the 
 //adjacent right element will be exchanged as after removing an element i.e. j,
 //odd terms on the right will become even and vice-versa.So we just have to 
 // calculate overall sum of even terms till that number(which we are removing) 
 //and sum of odd numbers i.e. temp[j+1][0] after j and compare it with overall  
 //sum of odd terms till j and sum of even numbers i.e. temp[j+1][1] after j
 int countEven=0//sum of even terms till j
 int countOdd=0//sum of odd terms till j
 int ans[];
 for j in range(0,len(arr)-1):
     if(countEven+temp[j+1][0]==countOdd+temp[j+1][1])
         ans+=j //one of our answer
     if(j%2==1)//checking whether the index is odd or not
          countOdd+=arr[j]
     else
          countEven+=arr[j]
 return ans;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it in a one-liner:

```js
const arr = [2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9];

const sums=arr.reduce((a,c,i)=>(a[i%2]+=c,a),[0,0]);

console.log(sums)
```

The first index of `sums` holds the sums of all even indexes and the second one the odd indexes.